# Why is this Android code so slow?

Tags: java, android, performance, canvas

I have a contour plot rendering routine that is *blazing* fast.  It basically renders to a form in the OnPaint event, and updates very quickly... basically as fast as you can move a mouse.  I was very pleased with it.  It's based on this paper:

http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/

However, I ported it to Android/Java and targeted a very fast tablet (Nexus 9) and it is surprisingly slow, to the point where I feel like I must be using the wrong approach.  Basically I:

1) create a view programmatically,
2) implement the onDraw method to call my cContourPlot class Draw method, which
3) iterates through a 2-D data array, compares to a 1-D "bins" array, and makes a few thousand calls to the "DrawPolygonRegion" function I wrote below.

This takes a surprisingly long time, about 100x slower than in .NET., to the point where I am wondering if I'm doing something wrong.  Specific questions:

a) Is the function below speed-tweakable?  Is there a faster way to draw a polygon than using a Path?  (in .NET there is a DrawPolygon function, had to make something new for the Android port)
b) Do I need to do something to "batch" my rendering commands?  Such as (imagined:) Canvas.SuspendUpdates, Canvas.ResumeUpdates?
c) Do I need to activate double buffering or something?  My quick research says this is done automatically in Android, but not sure. (I had to activate it in .NET but not sure if I have to here)

Thanks a lot for any insight/help.

```
void DrawPolygonRegion(Canvas c, int color, double ... p)
{
    int length = p.length;

    if (length >= 6)
    {
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo((float) p[0], (float) p[1]); // used for first point
        path.lineTo((float) p[2], (float) p[3]);
        path.lineTo((float) p[4], (float) p[5]);

        int idx = 6;

        for (int n=6; n<length; n+=2)
        {
            path.lineTo((float) p[n], (float) p[n+1]);
        }

        c.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Traceview and determine where your problem lies.

Comment: One thing I would do is replace `Path path = new Path()` with `path.rewind()` or (slightly slower) `path.reset()`. Keep the `path` object global to the class's scope.  This prevents thousands of `Path` objects from being created/garbage collected.  Not sure if this is the biggest root cause, but it is a contributor.

Answer (score 4):

Calling this a few thousand times.  Oh yeah, you got some problems.

1)It allocates a new Path.  Allocations add up quickly on Android.  Try to avoid them.  Prefer to reuse objects, especially in functions like onDraw.

2)You really ought to not be creating whole paths all the time anyway-  they're better off saved and reused in append mode.

3)Downcasting from double to float isn't free.  Avoid it

4)Are you doing this directly to the screen Canvas?  Don't.  Do it to a bitmap canvas in its own thread, and blit the results to the screen canvas.

I really doubt this code is blazing fast even in .NET on a PC with a better processor and RAM.  I think your butt is being saved there by hardware acceleration.

Comment: 1) will try that and report back, (2) don't understand, the polygons could change every paint so a caching system wouldn't help much.... but what do you mean "append mode"? (3)  will try that and report back (4) will try that, don't suppose you know of an example or keywords to search?  (hw accel) thats fine but why isn't hardware acceleration similarly helping me here?

Comment: By the way on the comparison with .NET... GDI rendering to a WinForm is generally blazing fast because it is a thin wrapper on the same subsystem used by the OS and all the other apps.  You're not going to do much better w/o circumventing the OS.  I figured that using onDraw and a view would be analogous -- the same API that Android itself uses (including optimized for HW accel, double buffering, all that good stuff), hence very fast.  Was this a bad assumption?  Is there a different technology or API I should be using?

Comment: It is the API Android itself uses.  But it doesn't give you all of that (for that matter windows GDI functions didn't a version or two back of windows).  Not to mention lower resources all around.  If you're drawing thousands of polygons per frame these things above ought to help, but you probably will end up needing to move to openGL.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still surprised.  Take your basic Android home screen -- it's a nice screen, I'm sure there are thousands of polygons there (in addition to a lot of pre-rendered bitmaps, I'm sure), right?  If I am using the same API in the same way that the OS does I'd expect to be in great shape, several hundred or a thousand draw commands would be nothing, not noticeable at least (noticeable = 200msec).

Comment: ... I'm basically hopeful that your suggestion above of rendering directly to a memory canvas will do a lot for me.

Comment: THe android homescreen is almost all pre-rendered bitmaps, with either some shader effects or a rotation matrix installed.  All those app icons are pre-rendered bitmaps.  The background will be either pre-rendered or a programmatic gradient which will be rendered once.